# Object Pascal: Must all objects (classes) be freed?

Tags: oop, pascal, freepascal, delphi

Can I throw around `class`es without freeing them, or will my software start spouting leaks?

For example can I do this

```
Engine := TEngine.Create(TV);
```

Then get rid of the reference without any problems, or must I call its `Free` method first?

Or have a function that returns a `TSomething` and not having to free its reference later on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general rule is that if you create it, you should free it. The best way is in a try..finally if you're creating it in code:

```
var
  Engine: TEngine;
begin
  Engine := TEngine.Create(TV);
  try
    // Do stuff with Engine
  finally
    Engine.Free;
  end;
end;
```

The exception to this is if you have an object that accepts an owner as a parameter (such as a visual control like `TEdit` or a non-visual descendant of `TComponent`). If you assign the owner, it will free it when the owner is freed. (If you create it without an owner, you still have to free it yourself.)

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  EditA, EditB: TEdit;
begin
  EditA := TEdit.Create(Self);  // You're passing the form as owner; don't free
  EditB := TEdit.Create(nil);   // Creating without an owner; you free.
end;
```

If the class is a member (field) of another object, you create it in the containing objects `constructor` and free it in its `destructor`:

```
type
  TOuterClass = class(TObject)
  private
    FEngine: TEngine;
  public
    constructor Create;
    destructor Destroy; override;
  end;

implementation

constructor TOuterClass.Create;
begin
  inherited;
  FEngine := TEngine.Create(TV);
end;

destructor TOuterClass.Destroy;
begin
  FEngine.Free;
  inherited;
end;
```

Comment: It can't be stressed enough that the TComponent owner mechanism is purely a library convention. On the language level it still must be freed, it is just that the FCL/VCL does some administration for you.

Comment: @KenWhite Do you also have to free raised `Exception`s?

Comment: @SuperDisk: No. :-) You're not creating them the same; you're *raising* them. The exception handling mechanism will take care of that for you.

Comment: @KenWhite Alright, one last question. Do you have to free a new class immediately passed to a procedure? For instance, if you call `DoThing(TCoord.Create(0, 0));` Do you have to free the `TCoord` within the `DoThing` method?

Comment: It depends on what `TCoord` is, but if it's an object instance then yes, you should. (It's a bad technique, though, because it doesn't clearly indicate who should clean up. The better solution, IMO, is to pass the `0, 0` to `DoThing` and let `DoThing` create the `TCoord` with those values, use it, and then free it when done.)

Answer (score 1):

Technically yes, everything that you initialize with a constructor must be freed explicitly.

But there are some easy workarounds that when used properly, can save you most of the trouble:

1: Use TInterfacedObject:

```
  IMyStuff = interface(IUnknown)
    ['{9DF82155-2475-4403-8933-969DC4912AD7}']
    function Print:boolean;
    procedure DoStuff;
  end;

  TMyStuff = class(TInterfacedObject, IMyStuff)
    private
      function Print:boolean;
      procedure DoStuff;
   end;
```

Implement TMyStuff just like any other class. But when you USE that class in your code, use a variable of type IMyStuff, like this:

```
procedure MyIProcedure;
var myStuff: IMyStuff;
begin

   myStuff:=TMyStuff.create;
   myStuff.DoStuff;

end;
```

No need to cast in the 'TMyStuff.create' call (in this case - sometimes it is...) - since the variable is type IMystuff this is implicit. No need to free IMyStuff ( In fact you can't, although you can call IMyStuff:=nil.) Since it is declared as an interface type, automated garbage collection is implemented using the the COM reference counting model - Delphi handles this for you when you inherit from TInterfacedObject.

**BUT** do not mix  class type variables: i.e. TMyStuff with IMyStuff variable types. This can lead to some nasty confusion and errors that will leave you scratching your head. That is the reason I generally declare members of TInterfacedObject as **PRIVATE**, as I did here, making them in inaccessible via references to TMyStuff. However they are accesible via a reference to IMyStuff: all interface members are public, by definition.

2: Besides Ken's excellent answer, the VCL's TObjectList and TObjectDictionary provide automated garbage collection for all the object references they contain (see Delphi docs for details) - but they themselves must be freed, and then the rest gets freed with them.

Use TObjectList or TObjectDictionary in a TInterfacedObject and never worry about garbage collection again, as long as you free the ObjectList or ObjectDictionary in the destructor of your TInterfacedObject. That destructor will be called automatically by Delph's implementation when referenceCount=0.