# how to define classes inside classes in delphi?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2009

I am in the progress of trying to learn a few new tricks in order to better organize some of the sourcecode in my units in Delphi.
I have noticed that some functions or methods I access appear to be classes inside classes, but I have not yet been successful in making a working class inside a class, although it compiles fine, I still get error messages when executing the code.

What I would like to do is to make kind of a tree with functions, procedures and values to set or get. I would be grateful if somebody could help me out a little bit with an example.
I have today some classes that are Types.
I then assign the types to a variable:
    something=TSomething
and Then for something to happen I write "something.action".

My aim is to go further, and define sub-functions or/and sub-procedures.
Lets say I have three or four classes. TSnippet, TAction1, TAction2, TSubAction1, Etc.
I would like to use or assign these to a single variable and use them like:

```
Snippet.Action1.SubAction1.Organize(param1,param2);
Snippet.Action2.SubAction2.Returns='SomeString';
Snippet.Action1.SubAction1.SomeProcedure;
```

Is anybody able to help me with a useful example as in how to write code for this approach to work?
And also.. does anybydy know how such an implementation of code will affect CPYCycles needed in order to execute code versus the old fashioned method of having thousands of procedures with all different names, but more direct access (it feels like more direct access).

As of my first text was maybe a bit unclear, this follows.
I would like to make use of the editors automatic suggestions of procedures/functions available in order to simplify programming a little bit.
I started to make a Class for this, and it works great.
Consider a classname "Data". What can we do with data? We can Edit, Add, Delete, Save and Load.
Ok. This is my first Class.

Consider then another Class: "Encrypt". We can do DES, DES3, HASH, BITSHUFFLE.
I can go on with a third Class: "Compress". We can do LZW, ZIP, RAR, MP3, MPG, MP4, etc.

Instead of using these as 3 different classes, I would like to combine them in one, yet keeping them separate.
I would like to make a kind of an OwnerClass for the other classes. We can call this "MyStuff"

Whenever I type "MyStuff." in the editor, I should get up a list of "Data, Encrypt, Compress".  Further, When I then choose "Compress", the next list for that class' procedures and functions will list up.

The classes may have some local variables, but the main functionality will be towards global arrays.

Maybe there are other ways of achieving this. I don't know.
My basic aim is to be able to categorize and put together routines that belong together.
This is already done in Units, but this does not help with the automatic list from the editor.
Thank you in advance.
Morten.

Comment: Your question is very unclear.  Can you [edit] to give an example of a case of an actual function or method that appears to be classes inside classes that you mention noticing?

Comment: You realize that anything declared in the implementation section is inherently private to that unit even if it's not declared inside something else?

Comment: @MortenBrendefur: to echo Ken's comment, your question is quite vague. Some clear code examples of your problem would help us give you the right answer. 'Classes that are types' doesn't make sense: all classes are types-and you must declare them in a Type section. And 'a class inside a class' CAN BE DONE-but I never had the need to do such a thing in 20 years of OOP. Just use object composition and delegation: One class refers to or generates an instance of a separate class. The visibility of classes to others is determined by the uses clause, access modifiers, placement in the unit, etc.

Comment: @MortenBrendefur: as far as performance considerations are concerned, unless you're working in some sort of very limited embedded device, with modern hardware, the difference in performance will be so miniscule that it's not worth considering unless you're in some sort of VERY TIGHT, VERY LONG loop - which is bad code to begin with. And more often than not, a good OOP design will be just as efficient as a procedural approach, if not better.

Comment: @Mikey: The last two to survive were `Delphi Informant` and `The Delphi Magazine` (aka `TDM`), IIRC. Both were pretty good.

Comment: @Mikey "Just use object composition and delegation". The tragic truth is that I don't know much about this. I can do anything when writing code, but the tricks you speak of.. I would need an example.
Please bear over me with my lack of knowledge in this matter.

Comment: @MortenBrendefur : What Ken White just answered you is an example of object composition (delegation is slightly different if you want to get really technical, but that's not the point here). One Object (class) contains references to other classes - creates and/or uses them. The object holding the references to the others is considered a 'composer' - combining and orchestrating the usage and behavior of the other classes it 'contains' and leverages for its tasks.

Comment: @Mikey
Thank you. I realize that I now have a few months work in order to transfer my older sourcecode into this "new" way of working and writing sourcecode. With simple examples, everything gets so much easier, and I am sure I can make it very complicated after a while :) The best part is that I see the clear advantage of this "new" approach of designing sourcecode.

Comment: @MortenBrendefur - you seem to have an urge to 'combine things'. Generally you should try keep things small and atomic. Research the term: 'Loose coupling'. You will understand what I mean. It is one of the most important concepts to keep in mind if you want to write code that is easy to debug and easy to fix and modify. Imagine if you had to remove the whole engine from your car every time you needed to change the battery. You don't have to do that because your car battery is 'loosely coupled' to the engine and the rest of the car. Extend this metaphor to your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I understand what it is you're asking, after your edit.

What you're calling "classes in classes" are called `properties` and `methods`; they're other classes, variables, or procedures/functions that are declared in their containing class. The "list" you're talking about is called `Code Insight`, and it shows you the available properties and methods of the class you're referencing in your code at that point.

This should do something like you describe, and give you an idea of how to implement it in your own code:

```
unit MyStuffUnit;

interface

uses
  SysUtils;

type

  TEncryptionType = (etDES, etDES3, etHASH, etBITSHUFFLE);

  TMyStuffEncryption = class(TObject)
  private
    FEncryptType: TEncryptionType;
  public
    constructor Create;
  published
    property EncryptionType: TEncryptionType read FEncryptType
      write FEncryptType;
  end;

  TCompressionType = (ctLZW, ctZIP, ctRAR, ctMP3, ctMPG, ctMP4);

  TMyStuffCompression = class(TObject)
  private
    FCompressionType: TCompressionType;
  public
    constructor Create;
  published
    property CompressionType: TCompressionType read FCompressionType
      write FCompressionType;
  end;

  TMyStuff = class(TObject)
  private
    FCompression: TMyStuffCompression;
    FEncryption: TMyStuffEncryption;
  public
    constructor Create;
    destructor Destroy; override;
  published
    property Compression: TMyStuffCompression read FCompression
      write FCompression;
    property Encryption: TMyStuffEncryption read FEncryption
      write FEncryption;
  end;

implementation

constructor TMyStuffEncryption.Create;
begin
  inherited;
  FEncryptType := etDES;
end;

constructor TMyStuffCompression.Create;
begin
  inherited;
  FCompressionType := ctLZW;
end;

constructor TMyStuff.Create;
begin
  inherited;
  FCompression := TMyStuffCompression.Create;
  FEncryption := TMyStuffEncryption.Create;
end;

destructor TMyStuff.Destroy;
begin
  FCompression.Free;
  FEncryption.Free;
  inherited;
end;

end.
```

If you create an instance of `TMyStuff` in your code, you should be able to type `MyStuff.` and get the option of choosing `Compression` or `Encryption`. Choosing `Compression` should allow you to set the `CompressionType` property.

[image]

This should be enough to get you going. :-) Remember that Delphi includes the source code for the VCL and RTL in almost all editions, so you always have that to look at for examples. (They're not always the very best examples, but they should give you ideas on how to do things.)

Comment: Thank you very much for this example. I will test it back and forth a little bit.
If I may, I do have one more question though.
The Create and Free. . . I suppose they just "load" the function into memory when needed, and then releases the memory afterwards?
How about just creating in the initialization part? 
When exiting the program, does it need to be freed? or is this done automatically ?

Comment: That's a separate question. :-) It's done automatically when your app is terminated, but not otherwise. In other words, if you create a single instance in `initialization` and need it to exist for the lifetime of your app, it will be released (along with the other memory of your app) when it terminates. If you need to create multiples, you should free them yourself (as I partly illustrated in my image with `try..finally`). `Create->try->use->finally-free`.

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15994120/62576) I posted earlier might help with your additional question.

Comment: Thank you very much. For my uses so far, I only need one instance for the lifetime of the application (That is my actual general idea), but I can already think of some of my work where it will be most useful with more than one instance:)

Comment: @MortenBrendefur:initialization and finalization sections get tricky: They run when a unit is loaded first time and outside the scope of the built-in Delphi exception handler. Makes debugging in those sections more difficult, and can cause some odd runtime behavior. Generally we use those sections only in very discreet ways such as Ken mentioned: for example a singleton class factory factory that you always want to be available-Delphi does for that for its COM object implementations. You also cannot declare types there or access modifiers, etc-they are outside the OOP way of doing things.